# GitHub não reconhece arquivo de formato personalizado

Tags: git, github

Estou tentando fazer upload de certos arquivos em um repositório no GitHub. Porém, após realizado o pull request, o arquivo não está lá. Quando executo o comando git add . {Pasta} ele não reconhece os formatos (.rv0 , .new). Poderia me ser util saber quais arquivos o GitHub reconhece.

Comment: verifique o arquivo `.gitignore` deve ser isso.

Comment: Existe também a possibilidade de forçar adicionar o arquivo (se ele estiver realmente listado no .gitignore). Veja na [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add). `git add --force /meu/arquivo/extensão.rv0`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Dentro do repositório principal tem um arquivo `.gitignore` la dentro tem `"#Remove in/output files"`, vai ter as restrições